# Mac-friendly hotkeys?

Tags: windows, macos, hotkeys, emulation

We get more and more customers that install our Windows application on Macs (via Bootcamp, WMWare, Parallels or Wine). We use TAB, Insert and Home as hotkeys for quick toggling of features.

Are there good alternatives to Home and Insert that would be easier to access on a Mac keyboard?

Comment: Doesn't macs have a home key???

Comment: Not to be too much of a smart-ass, but if they're going to jump through the hoops of Bootcamp, et.al., shouldn't they be astute enough to ascertain the equivalent keys on their Mac?  (BTW, I own a Mac and sure don't expect that anybody who sells Windows software is going to support emulator users with questions like this)

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I agree, but schools in Sweden have started to provide each student with a laptop. Some of them are handing out MacBooks. It is great marketing if the students can use our software in school. If we can make that easier it is a good investment.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343

Comment: These to articles are more relevant to keyboard mapping:
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1167 and http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1220